# Can different functions be used to extract different types of layers of a raster using terra::extract?

Tags: r, extract, terra

My goal is to extract data from a **raster** for a set of **polygon** locations. The raster has many numeric variables and some categorical. I would like to extract the values conditional on this, e.i., if the variable is numeric get the `mean` for each polygon and if the variable is categorical get the `mode`.

Now I'm doing this (see that the 'numeric' layer is numeric, and the 'categorical' has numbers that represent categories):

```
extract_numeric <- terra::extract(x = raster,
                                  y = vect(polygons),
                                  fun = mean,
                                  layer = 'numeric',
                                  rm.na=T)

extract_categorical <- terra::extract(x = raster,
                                      y = vect(polygons),
                                      fun = mode,
                                      layer = 'categorical',
                                      rm.na=T)

extract <- c(extract_numeric, extract_categorical)
```

Is it possible to extract the values all in one depending on the layer type? Even if I would like that different numeric layers get different `fun` for the extraction. Can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could use a custom `fun` that chooses mean or mode depending on the layer type.  BTW, providing a minimal reproducible example really helps people to test potential solutions.  Almost all questions, with only few exceptions, should include an MRE.  What is missing here is some example data for the raster object.

Comment: ... but honestly, I wonder how much it is even a good idea to mix up the types like this.  Probably it is cleaner to just keep them separate.  Otherwise, how can we be sure that the results can all be coerced to a single type in the final vector without losing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that cannot be done. What you can also do is subset `x` using names or indices

```
e_num <- extract(x[[c(1:3, 6:8)]], v, fun=mean)
e_cat <- extract(x[[4:5]], v, fun=mean)
```

But that is similar to using the `layer` argument.

You can also do

```
e_list <- extract(x, v)
```

And then `lapply` your own function on that list.